# TFS 2013 Express -- Can I Upgrade to Licensed Version from Express?

Tags: tfs

Can I upgrade from an Express version to a licensed version, without having to uninstall the Express version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to uninstall express in order to install the full version of tfs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620928.aspx

Comment: They are all stored in the SQL Database. You can keep using SQL express up to 16GB DB's. So just uninstall TFS Express and install TFS Standard. As long as you do an "upgrade" all of your data will still be there.